# How to use GeoServer REST API to create mbtiles datastore

Tags: geoserver-rest-api

GeoServer adds support for mbtiles store   in  [support for mbtiles store](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/pull/4191/commits/dc1319dc1a6fe017804edbffcfc6b3adf24741d9).

But I try more times and fail. Somebody can give utils or curl command?

This is my curl command  in Java

```
String cmd = "curl -u " + geoUsername + ":" + geoPassword
            + " -XPUT "
            + " -H  \"Content-type: text/plain\""
            + " -d \"file:///D:/Tool/geoserver/outdir/AustinOpenStreetMap10-14.mbtiles\" "
            + geoUrl + "/rest/workspaces/storm/datastores/test_mbtiles10/external.mbtiles"
            ;
```

This is code in Java

```
HTTPUtils.post(geoUrl + "/rest/workspaces/storm/datastores", createMbTileStore(), "text/xml",geoUsername, geoPassword);

private static String createMbTileStore(){
    return "<dataStore>" +
            "<name>test_mbtiles11</name>" +
            "<connectionParameters>" +
                "<database>file:/D:/Tool/geoserver/outdir/AustinOpenStreetMap10.mbtiles</database>" +
                "<dbtype>mbtiles</dbtype>" +
            "</connectionParameters>" +
    "</dataStore>";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: please show us what you have tried and what the GeoServer log file shows for those failures